# Z coordinate expectation value of the Hydrogen atom

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-spin, atomic-physics, hydrogen

I want to find $z-coordinate$ expectation value $\textbf{<z>}$ of the Hydrogen atom wave function $\psi_{1,0,0} = (\pi a^3_0)^{-1/2}e^{-r/a_0}$ in its ground state.

I read in some text that $<z> = 0$ by symmetry. However, I don't understand the symmetric relation of the coordinates.

I tried the following:

I know that $<z> = <r\cos\phi> $ from the spherical coordinate system. I need to take integral of $r\cos\phi$. I don't know how to continue from here. Any suggestion, how can I solve this problem?

Comment: This is the 2s orbital and is radially symmetric so it is an even function of $z$. $z$ itself is an odd function of $z$ so $z\psi_\text{2s}$ is odd and its expectation value will therefore be zero. Did you mean the expectation value of $|z|$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$\langle z\rangle=\int_0^\infty r^3dr[\int_0^{2\pi}d\phi\int_0^\pi \sin \theta \cos \theta d\theta]=0$ As the $\theta $ integration is zero.

But the symmetry argument is clear if the integration is written is Cartesian coordinates.In that case $$\langle z\rangle=\int_{-\infty}^\infty  \int_{-\infty}^\infty \int_{-\infty}^\infty z dz |\psi|^2 dx dy$$

As you can see the integration over $z$ is odd and therefore zero.